# MongoDB: Query a key having space in its name

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to retrieve values of only certain keys from a MongoDB collection.

But, the collection has some keys which have a 'space' in their name like:

```
"Parent":{"key1": //some string,
          "key2": //some string,
          "key 3": //some string}
```

I know this is a wrong approach as there shouldn't ideally be spaces in a key name but nevertheless how do I query this key? I am using Python and PyMongo.

For normal keys I can do this:

```
db.coll_name.find({"key": "India"}, {"_id": 0, "Parent.key1": 1, "Parent.key2": 1})
```

So how do I use the key "Parent['key 3']" in the second argument of the above query?  Is there any way to achieve this?

**Here's the query which returns data(works):**

```
db.coll_name.find({}, {"Parent.key1": 1, "_id": 0})
```

**Here's the query which doesn't return data:**

```
db.coll_name.find({}, {"Parent['key 3']": 1, "_id": 0})
```

Comment: what is wrong with `{'key 3': 1}`? Now if you don't know how many spaces in the key. Well I suggest you to update your documents and remove spaces from keys

Comment: Sorry, edited the question a little. Please have a look. "Parent['key 3']" doesn't work. Only the dot notation is working.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an error? What is is? What code are you actually running to do this (you haven't posted that)

Comment: No, there is no error. But it returns an empty object. Updated the question with code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well the only way you could have constructed this is like:

```
content = {};
content["Parent"] = {}
content["Parent"]["key2"] = 1
content["Parent"]["key 3"] = 1

db.coll_name.insert(content)
```

But you seem to be missing that there is nothing wrong with doing this:

```
db.coll_name.find({ "Parent.key 3":  1} )
```

Or in projection

```
 db.coll_name.find({}, { "Parent.key 3": 1 })
```

It's ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) and not object notation, and as long as you quote the key names ( which is mandatory for dot notation ) then all it fine and you can have a space in there.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!, didn't realize that using the dot notation like that was a valid approach. :)

Comment: Reason #37 why I love mongo

Answer (score 1):

> I know this is a wrong approach as there shouldn't ideally be spaces in a key name but nevertheless how do I query this key?

What I will suggest is:

- Remove space from documents key using [`bulk write operations`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html#bulk-write-operations)

  ```
  bulk = coll_name.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
  count = 1000

  for doc in coll_name.find():
      parent = {}
      parent.setdefault('Parent', {})
      for key, val in doc['Parent'].items():
          parent['Parent'][key.replace(' ', '')] = val
          bulk.find({'_id': doc['_id']}).update({'$set': parent})
          count += 1
          if count % 1000 == 0:
              # Execute per 1000 operations and re-init.
              bulk.execute()
              bulk = coll_name.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
  # Clean up queues
  if count % 1000 != 0:
      bulk.execute()
  ```
- Then your projection become simpler

  ```
  db.coll_name.find({'key': 'India'}, {'_id': 0, 'Parent.key1': 1, 'Parent.key2': 1, 'Parent.key3': 1 })
  ```