# Mongoose Query Nested Data Multiple Word Key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I cannot find an example of how to build a query where the property name of a nested property is multiple words.

```
var student = {
  name: 'Kevin',
  address: {
    'Street 1': '123 Main',
    'Street 2': 'Apt 2'
    city: 'Chicago'
};

// This works.
var query = Student.find({
  'address.city': 'Chicago'
});
```

I cannot figure out how to query by Street 1.

```
// Tried this. Did not work.
var query = Student.find({
  'address["Street 1"]': '123 Main'
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Query a key having space in its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367145/mongodb-query-a-key-having-space-in-its-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same dot notation syntax, it should work:

```
// Tried this. It works.
var query = Student.find({
  'address.Street 1': '123 Main'
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was making it too complicated.